# React chartjs - chart stays empty unless legend is clicked twice

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I am trying to make a chart in react by first retrieving some data from axios requests, so I am able to show a chart but it stays empty. When I click the legend twice it does show the data, but I want to show the data immediately. Anyone able to have a look at my code? I've been struggling for a couple of hours with creating a chart because I couldn't send over the data through states but that should be 'fixed' now. Except for the double legend clicking issue of course..

This is my the page where I want to load my chart:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Chart from "./Chart.js";

export default class extends Component {
    state = {
        packageData: {}
    }

    async getData() {
        let count = [];
        await axios.get(`/getCountExpress`)
            .then(res => {
                count.push(res.data[0].count);
            });
        await axios.get(`/getCountEconomy`)
            .then(res => {
                count.push(res.data[0].count);
            });
        await axios.get(`/getCountInternational`)
            .then(res => {
                count.push(res.data[0].count);
            });
        return Promise.all(count);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        let types = [];
        this.getData().then(values => {
            values.forEach(value => types.push(value));
        });
        this.setState({
            packageData: {
                labels: ['Express', 'Economy', 'International'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Amount of packages',
                    data: types,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                        'rgba(38, 166, 91, 1)',
                        'rgba(44, 130, 201, 1)']
                }]
            }
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.packageData.datasets);
        });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '20px' }}>Statistics</h2>
                <Chart chartData={this.state.packageData} />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is my chart component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: props.chartData
    }
  }

  options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        <Bar
          data={this.state.chartData} options={this.options}

        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So anyone knows what the issue could be? Why does it not load the data immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to change your approach. You should start your state with an empty value. thus, your graphic is not going to break on the rendering.

Have a look on this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-star-9z1rf

Hope that can help you.